# What's the combined wealth of the US banks?

Tags: banking, wealth

How much is the amount of money of the US banks?

In terms of:

- assets
- their own money (the banks make profits and they can keep the profits for further investments)

The question is only about the banks. No retirement funds, no venture capitals, no other kind of financial institutions.

Answer (score 2):

The [total assets](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/TLAACBW027SBOG) of all US commercial banks are about \$17.2 trillion.

You'll have to be clearer about what you mean by "their own money". The [total equity capital](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/USTEQC) of US commercial banks is about \$1.9 trillion.

Comment: Say a bank starts with a capital (the money the owners of the banks put to start the bank) of 1 billion \$US. So their own money is 1 billion $US. Then they make profits every year, growing their wealth, so after five years the bank has 2 billion \$US. This is their own capital and it does not include assets. I there a better term for that?